# Example of differences in "Expressiveness" in graphDB rulesets (RDFS-Plus) vs Protege (Pellet/Hermit)

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege, graphdb

I am having trouble importing my Protege 5 ontology into graphDB and seeing the inferred classes. This is due to different "expressiveness" in the programs' reasoners' approaches. Can someone explain how these two programs "line-up" in terms of expressiveness. I am trying to figure out why Pellet Et al. can correctly infer complex classes but graphDB doesn't, an example would really help clarify the boundary.

Comment: Pellet, HermiT, and all other DL reasoners do support full OWL 2 DL, that's out of scope for rule based approaches. What GraphDB support or not is online. Limitations of rule-based approaches can be found e.g. at OWL RL specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#OWL_2_RL

Comment: But as said last time, it's unclear what exactly you miss

Answer (score 0):

Without an example from your ontology, the question has too many possible answers.

Picking one possibility: if you define equivalent classes with OWL axioms those would not be axioms an RDF reasoner would understand. Therefore, inferences would be lost. Same for any other owl axiom that uses vocabulary that is not taken from RDF or RDFS.